# (Beginner Python assignment help) Search input list

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, search

I have just started learning python and i have been given an assignment to create a list of players and stats using different loops.
I cant work out how to create a function that searches the player list and gives an output of the players name and the players stat.

**Here is the assignment:**

> 1. Create an empty list called players
> 2. Use two `input()` statements inside a for loop to collect the name
>      and performance of each player (the name will be in the form of a
>      string and the performance as an integer from 0 – 100.) Add both
>      pieces of information to the list (so in the first iteration of the
>      loop `players[0]` will contain the name of the first  player and
>      `players[1]` will contain their performance.) You are not required to
>      validate this data.
> 3. Use a while loop to display all the player information in the
>      following form:
>
> Player : Performance
>
> 4. Use a loop type of your choice to copy the performance values from
>      the players list and store these items in a new list called results
> 5. Write a function that accepts the values  “max” or “min” and
>      returns the maximum or minimum values from the results list
> 6. Write a function called `find_player()` that accepts a player name
>      and displays their name and performance from the players list, or an
>      error message if the player is not found.

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
print ("Enter 11 Player names and stats")

# Create player list
playerlist = []

# Create results list
results = []

# for loop setting amount of players and collecting input/appending list
for i in range(11):
    player = (input("Player name: "))
    playerlist.append(player)
    stats = int(input("Player stats: "))
    playerlist.append(stats)

# While loop printing player list
whileLoop = True
while whileLoop == True:
  print (playerlist)
  break

# for loop append results list, [start:stop:step]
for i in range(11):
  results.append(playerlist[1::2])
  break  

# max in a custom function
def getMax(results):
    results = (playerlist[1::2])
    return max(results)
print ("Max Stat",getMax(results))


# custom function to find player 
def find_player(playerlist): 
  list = playerlist
  name = str(input("Search keyword: "))
  return (name)
  for s in list:
    if name in str(s):
        return (s)

print (find_player(playerlist))
```

I have tried many different ways to create the find player function without success.
I think I am having problems because my list consists of strings and integers eg. `['john', 6, 'bill', 8]`
I would like it to display the player that was searched for and the stats `['John', 6]`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS:
*I know there is no need for all these loops but that is what the assignment seems to be asking for.*

Thank you

Comment: Small comments on your code:
You can delete the whilelloop variable. You can just do `while True:` and `break` out of it. I would also recommend asking for the name to search outside of the find_player function and passing the name as a second parameter. Just feels more appropriate, but it doesn't change the requirement according to the assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cut down on the fat and made a "dummy list", but your find_player function seems to work well, once you remove the **first** `return` statement! **Once you return something, the function just ends**.
All it needs is to also display the performance like so:

```
# Create player list
playerlist = ["a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3]


# custom function to find player 
def find_player(playerlist): 
    name = str(input("Search keyword: "))
    searchIndex = 0
    for s in playerlist:
        try:
            if name == str(s):
                return ("Player: '%s' with performance %d" % (name, playerlist[searchIndex+1]))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        searchIndex += 1

print (find_player(playerlist))

>>Search keyword: a
>>Player: 'a' with performance 1
```

I also added a try/except in case something goes wrong.

Also: NEVER USE "LIST" AS A VARIABLE NAME!
Besides, you already have an internal name for it, so why assign it another name. You can just use playerlist inside the function.

Comment: SIDEBAR: Instead of assigning two items to the list, I would recommend making a tuple of (name,preformance) and assign that to the list. Its just easier to comprehend as a data structure. Its not what the assignment says, but just something to think about choosing appropriate data types for you task

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't work because you typed a key and immediately returned it. In order for the code to work, you must use the key to find the value. In this task, it is in the format of '' key1 ', value1,' key2 ', value2, ...]. In the function, index is a variable that stores the position of the key. And it finds the position of key through loop. It then returns list [index + 1] to return the value corresponding to the key.

```
playerlist = []

def find_player(playerlist):
  list = playerlist
  name = str(input("Search keyword: "))
  index = 0
  for s in list:
    if name == str(s):
        return ("This keyword's value: %d" % (list[index+1]))
    index+=1

print (find_player(playerlist))
```